# Does (will) wind affect plasma (electical spark passing through a gap)?

Tags: plasma-physics

Does (will) wind affect plasma (electical spark passing through a gap) in a way such as it affects fire?

My guess is no because it's like light, but still thought its worth asking.

Thanks

Comment: It's more similar to fire than to light.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it definitely does. Otherwise, the [Jacob's ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aJacobs_Ladder_HM.jpg) wouldn't work: therein, an electric arc moves upwards. This is because it heats the air around it, which then expands, reducing its density, thus causing an upwards "wind" which pulls the electric arc with it.

---

> I think that once it is plasma it can no longer be affected because at that time it turns into electromagnetic radiation in the form of light?

Well, no. As Jaime said, plasma is just ionised gas, but still gas. To put it on a particle level: it still consists of electrons and nuclei, i.e. of fermions, these [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number#Conservation_laws_for_leptonic_numbers) [just vanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number#Conservation)¹. Air consists of the same fermions, and fermions of the same kind [repulse each other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle#Consequences), which in this case means the plasma is pushed around by moving air.

In contrast, electromagnetic radiation / light consists of photons, which are bosons, not fermions.

---

¹Certainly not at such low energies – in an electric arc we can't have more than the few $\mathrm{keV}$s supplied by the electric voltage, which is far to low for serious elementary-particle reactions.

Comment: I don't think wind or anything physical can affect plasma directly. Only the air before it turns into plasma can be physically affected. I think that once it is plasma it can no longer be affected because at that time it turns into electromagnetic radiation in the form of light?

Comment: Plasma is an ionized gas, not electromagnetic radiation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics) so it is affected by ordinary physical phenomena such as wind similarly to how any other gas would.

Comment: Jacobs ladder: http://io9.com/5881578/the-weird-physics-behind-the-jacobs-ladder-frankensteins-favorite-prop "The electrons do look for the path of least resistance, but the path of least resistance is always where the plasma is. And the moving electrons heat the plasma around them. This ionized air is less dense than the surrounding air, and moves upwards. The electrons follow it, until at last the jump becomes too far for them, and the connection is lost. "